# WCF client instance creating

Tags: c#, wcf

What is the best way to connect to WCF service? I mean what approach is better:

1. creating DataServiceClient instance every time i want to  invoke WCF API function, or
2. create DataServiceClient instance once, when the app starts and propagate it across whole app.

Is the first way less efficient than the second one?

Answer (score 1):

It's argumentative but the

> creating DataServiceClient instance every time i want to invoke WCF
>   API function, or

Will give a lazy instantiation. That's don't create a proxy object unless needed. Whereas

> create DataServiceClient instance once, when the app starts and
>   propagate it across whole app.

Will go for a eager instantiation. You are unnecessarily creating a proxy object even though you may not need that right off.

Best is, in whichever class / Form class; you need to consume WCF service method; create a proxy object in the class/Form constructor and use the same instance. Like

```
Public class Form1 : Form
{
  private proxyobjecttype _client;

public Form1()
{
  _client = mywcfnamespace.Proxyobject();
}

private void someconsumermethod()
{
  _client.callWCFmethod1();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on frequency which you intend to send queries with and on the protocol you use.

If it's just a one request per long time interval it worth closing the client in order to spare system resources.

If you're planning to perform a series of queries, it would be better to retain the client till the end of the series.

Finally, you can implement a pool of clients in case of significant client creation cost (e.g. long connection timeouts in your network).